# Simulate long click on calabash-android

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calabash

I have problem with simule long press click on android.
I don't use pre-definied steps, but I need use command from ruby console.
Can You help me?

Comment: I found solution
`long_press(uiquery, options = {})`

Comment: Answer it yourself here :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

Keypress with validation - `long_press_when_element_exists(query_string, options = {})`

or

Keypress only `long_press(query_string, options = {})`